# Getting the ID of selected item in Combobox windows form

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

i am working on a C# windows form application. i wanted to get id of the selected item in combo box. below is my code.

```
  private void ProductForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCeConnection Connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConString);
        Connection.Open();
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select * from CastingMaterial", Connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ProductsComboBox.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["PartName"]);

        }
        ProductsComboBox.DisplayMember = "PartName";
        ProductsComboBox.ValueMember = "PartId";
        Connection.Close();
    }

    private void ProductsComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ProductIndex = ProductsComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        string productName = ProductsComboBox.Text.ToString();
        int ProductId =Convert.ToInt32(ProductsComboBox.SelectedValue);
        SqlCeConnection Connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConString);
        Connection.Open();
        String Query = "SELECT * From CastingMaterial where PartId=@PartId";
        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(Query, Connection);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("PartId", ProductId);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCeCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(da);

        BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

        da.Fill(ds, "CastingMaterial");
        bsource.DataSource = ds.Tables["CastingMaterial"];
        Productgv.DataSource = bsource;
        Connection.Close();
    }
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding items as DataRows. Instead, you are extracting the value from one of columns:

```
 ProductCombo.Items.Add( dt.Rows[i] );
```

Then you set the DisplayMember and ValueMember correctly, however, this has no effect since you add items incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, you need to post the question more clearly.

How would you like to get the selected ID of the combo box? 
And what purpose did you intended to use that ID for?

I think you should describe your actual problem more clearly here. 
Cause, the code seems to work fine for me.

And, btw, you don't actually need a loop for setting the data items of the combo box. You just have to assign the `DataSource` property of the combo to the DataTable into which you just extracted the data.

`ProductsComboBox.DataSource = dt` ...works just fine, you know!
Then, you can set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` to their respective columns.